# Phalcon transaction rollback - unable to get rational error message

Tags: transactions, phalcon, rollback

I got problem with getting proper error message when doing transaction rollback in Phalcon. Little piece of code:

```
if(!$mailingList->save()){
        $this->transaction->rollback("Can't save mailingList model");
        return (new IR(false))->setErrors(\Helpers\Response::getErrors($mailingList));
}
```

I've got my custom class "InternalResponse" aliased as "IR" which gives me all necessary information in debugging process, but when I do a rollback it prevents from returning my message to a higher level. In order to that I can't see what was the problem with saving model. I tried to pass my IR class as rollback parameter and also array containing errors but both approaches don't work, because rollback() accept just String as parameter.

I would appreciate if anyone could give me some clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transaction rollback throws an exception, so it would bypass that return statement because it's going to propagate up to the closest catch block, or the PHP runtime exception catcher.

If you want to re-throw the message or handle it some other way, do something like this:

```
try {
    if (!$mailingList->save()) {
        $this->transaction->rollback("Can't save mailingList model");
    }
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // $e->getMessage() === "Can't save mailingList model"
    return (new IR(false))->setErrors($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: This solution works perfect. Thanks for sharing this :)